# Fixing low FPS in Swift Playground

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift-playground

My SpriteKit playground book averaged 15 FPS on my MacBook Pro.

Do playgrounds run slower than iOS device simulations? If I run the same playground book on my iPad Pro, will the FPS limitation be similar? Will other apps opened on my computer limit the speed of playgrounds?

**EDIT:**
Moving code such as subclasses and extensions to auxiliary code in the "Sources" folder of the playground book allow the simulation to run quicker because the code only compiles once.

Comment: Have you tried running the app on an actual device? It's always a good practice if you do so instead of a simulator.

Comment: Playgrounds are awesome and convenient but slow, and they use the iOS simulator which is also slow. For SpriteKit you'd better make test apps and run them on a real device rather than using Playgrounds.

Comment: @Eric-Aya the rules for the WWDC17 scholarship challenge require a swift playground. Apple's Swift Playgrounds app contains 3D templates which run smoothly, so this baffles me.

Comment: @MichaelAustin This is Apple's fault actually but the mistake is that "Swift Playgrounds" on iPad is a very different app from an Xcode Playground on the Mac. As weird as it is, the Mac version is way behind the iPad version in terms of performance (and usability).

Comment: @EricAya so when ported to my iPad it will run faster?

Comment: @MichaelAustin I can't know for your specific code but yes, this is generally the case *if you're using stuff like SpriteKit, animations, etc*.

Comment: @EricAya if you want to, organize your info and I can accept the answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On the Mac, Xcode's "Playgrounds" are super useful for quick experiments but, due to their nature, terribly slow for "real" tasks.

If your code is more than a few pages long, and/or involves working with the UI, as you do with SpriteKit, the Playground may become really slow, sometimes even unresponsive.

"Playgrounds" are part of Xcode and run on top of the iOS simulator - that's how they display graphics and UI in the "Assitant Editor". The iOS simulator is not really known to be fast either.

On the other hand, "Swift Playgrounds" on iOS is a completely different app, even if it shares a lot with its Mac cousin.

Most importantly, it runs in iOS on the real device, with the real hardware processing, not emulation, which makes it ideal to use for SpriteKit, as Apple themselves often shows in their demos.

I would therefore say that your code should indeed run faster/better/properly on the iPad version.

*Even if of course, I can't really know, since I don't know your code - you will probably be the one telling us later if using the iPad version made a difference.*