# Swift playground with SceneKit has really low fps

Tags: ios, swift, opengl-es, swift-playground, metal

I'm working on some SceneKit project for WWDC, but I came across the issue where the fps in the playground live view is extremely low. Please see picture below.

This is the stats on a real device:

[image: Stats on a real decice]

This is the stats in the playground

[image: Stats in playground live view]

As you can see, the difference is quite significant. Also, does the live view even support Metal??? I know it's kinda like a simulator, so probably it only supports OpenGL? ("GL flush" instead of "Metal flush?")

Another issue is that if I try to pan-gesture the entire scene(it rotates), the fps drops to almost 0...It gets stuck....whereas in the iOS simulator which also uses OpenGL rendering, at least it will rotate without any problems.

The code is exactly the same in my playground file as in my xcproject.

Any help will be great!

Many thanks.

Comment: When you say Playground do you mean Swift-Playgrounds on iOS or Xcode-Playground on the Mac? This is not clear. // Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/42698862/2227743

Comment: @EricAya I'm using Xcode on mac, I don't have an iPad to test my code.

Comment: Then the duplicate answers your question: it's normal. Xcode's Playgrounds are slow. *One possible solution* is to move the more code you can to the "Sources" folder (mark it public first) which is only compiled once.

Comment: @EricAya No, I'm not complaining about compile time, it's the FPS during run time! Of course I know I should move my Model class into the source folder. But in Xcode, scene is rendered using OpenGL instead of Metal, this is the thing that annoys me, don't really want to buy an iPad.

Comment: "it's the FPS during run time" I know. Read the linked answer.

Comment: @EricAya I read it, all you suggested was to run on a real device which i don't have. I knew the issue, and my code is super clean. But is there a way to force the simulator to use my mac's GPU?

Comment: @EricAya Your answer is great, i'd give you an up vote, but it didn't solve my problem.

Comment: There is nothing to solve! :) My answer explains why you *cannot* have fast UI/graphics in Xcode's Playground. If you don't have an iOS device, it stops there, no magic solution.