# Swift: How to compile SKScene from another file? in Swift Playground?

Tags: swift, swift3, sprite-kit, swift-playground

Alright, I am constrained to working in a Swift playground on mac for a project and am having SERIOUS lagging issues because as read in [Low fps swift playgrounds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42698862/low-fps-swift-playgrounds) playgrounds are just slow as they compile continuously.

I have not written a lot of code but already just by adding the following in didMoveToView:

```
towerBase.texture = SKTexture()
        towerBase.size = CGSize(width: 500, height: 500)
        towerBase.position = CGPoint(x: 0,y: 0)
```

I lowered my fps from 40 to 20. Its ridiculous and animations are so choppy they don't even play.

Apparently by moving code to my sources folder this can be fixed according to above answer, so I need to know - how can I instantiate an Skscene from another class?

Im new to playgrounds also and don't know how I would do this in Swift playgrounds. Now in my main playground file I have:

```
import PlaygroundSupport
import SpriteKit
import XCPlayground

class GameScene: SKScene {
```