# Getting 5 fps iOS Simulator

Tags: sprite-kit, ios-simulator, lag

I'm running the starter project for SpriteKit and the simulators fps rate is around 5 or under. Thats so bad I can't do anything without serious lag.

Best regards,

[About computer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQtFy.png)
[iPhone Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GoWSy.png)

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/42705840/2227743 it's similar. TL;DR: the simulator is not an iPhone, it is not hardware accelerated. Quite the contrary...

Comment: @Moritz so what do I do? I have an android phone so i cant run the program on that

Comment: SpriteKit projects will not work properly in a simulator, you need an iOS device. No other way.

Comment: alright thanks @mor

Comment: Buy a second hand 6 Plus, with 16GB. This has fast storage, but slow everything else, so makes a good benchmarking and development mule.

Comment: Even cheaper than buying an iPhone, buy (new or second hand) a recent iPod touch (6th generation).